# Winforms Binding and Validation when mode is DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged

Tags: c#, winforms, validation, binding

I am trying to implement validation along with binding in my WinForms application.

I have an edition form with several properties bound to the same object, that implements INotifyPropertyChanged, and all my bindings are set to DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged.

My scenario is that when I edit some value, some others may be changed accordingly:

```
public class BindingRecord : INotifyPropertyChanged {
    #region INotify stufff - standard!!!
    {......}
    #endregion

    private string p1;
    private string p2;
    public BindingRecord () { }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Required Prop1")]
    public string Prop1 {
      get { return p1; }
      set { 
        p1 = value;
        RaisePropertyChanged("Prop1");
      }
    }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Required Prop2")]
    public string Prop2 {
      get { return p2; }
      set { 
        p2 = value;
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(p2) && [...some condition linking p1 & p2...]) {
          //!!!!! NOTE I use the 
          // PROPERTY => this raises the Notify event !!!!!
          Prop1 = "some value!!!"; 
        }
        RaisePropertyChanged("Prop2");
      }
    }
  }
```

In my form, I have two edit boxes bound to Prop1 and Prop2 with the OnPropertyChanged mode.

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {      
  // Empty binding re
  BindingRecord rec = new BindingRecord();
  rec.Prop1 = "";
  rec.Prop2 = "";
  //
  txtEdit1.DataBindings.Add("Text", rec, "Prop1", true, DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged);
  txtEdit2.DataBindings.Add("Text", rec, "Prop2", true, DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged);
  // validate children!!
  this.ValidateChildren();
}
```

Also, to make clear to the user which properties are mandatory, I call ValidateChildren once I enter the edition form => initially, both Prop1 and Prop2 are emtpy and hence with validation error.

The thing is, when I edit Prop2 (even before validation), I set the Prop1 and, as my binding is OnPropertyChange, this also updates the bound edit box correctly showing the "some value!!!" text.... BUT the validation error is still there...

So the question : how can I ensure that the VALIDATE of the control is called upon property change so that when I edit Prop2, the Prop1's validation error is cleared???

Thanks in advance!
Nik

Comment: Try raise Validation event manually in the `Prop1`. Validation on the `Prop1`wasn't raised because `txtEdit1` hasn't focus on it

Comment: Could you please clarify HOW I would validate ?
NOTE: I don't have access to of the txtEdit1/2 in Prop2...